# Bounding chain lengths in a "balls in boxes" poset

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization

> Given are constants $c_i>0$, $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, and $n$ indistinguishable balls distributed among $k$ distinguishable boxes as $(n_1,\dots, n_k)$ (so that $\sum_i n_i = n$).  We are allowed to move a ball from box $i$ to box $j$ if $c_j n_j < c_i (n_i -1)$.  Does there exist a constant $\lambda>0$ so that for any choice of $n,k,\{c_i\}_{i=1}^k$ this process necessarily stops after at most $\lambda n^2$ steps?

This can be thought of as follows: Each configuration of balls $(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ has an energy $\sum_i c_i (n_i^2 - n_i)$, and you are allowed to move a ball from one box to another only if it strictly lowers the energy.  (From this perspective, the tricky bit is that you are only allowed to move one ball at a time, which prevents you from hitting every state on the way from high energy to low.)

This problem was posed on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497605/balancing-balls-in-bins), and despite being bountied it did not get any responses that I think are likely to lead to a solution.  I've experimented with this problem a bit, and also with the somewhat more general problem where the energy has the form $\sum_i \phi_i(n_i)$, for arbitrary increasing, convex functions $\phi_i$, and I've not been able to find a case where you can take more than $\binom{n}{2}$ steps.  (EDIT: Peter Taylor pointed out that I was also assuming $\phi_i(1)=\phi_i(0)$ for this statement.  Without this extra hypothesis, it's easy to construct an example with twice as many steps, but this is still $<n^2$.)

I'm invested now, so I want to see if the big kids of MO can solve this one.

Comment: Can you find a constant that depends on $c$, say on the minimum $c_i$?

Comment: @usul I do not know how to do so.  If $\Delta c$ denotes the minimum of positive values of $c_i (n_i^2-n_i) - c_j (n_j^2 - n_j)$ over all $i\neq j$ and $n_i, n_j \leq n$, then the number of steps is bounded by $n^2 \times \max\{c_i\} / \Delta c$.  This $\Delta c$ depends on $n$, but it might be possible to show that $\Delta c$ asymptotes to a non-zero value for large $n$ (e.g. this is true for rational $c_i$), in which case it would give the sort of bound you suggest.  Why do you ask?  Is there a way to bootstrap such a bound to get something independent of the $c_i$?

Comment: Dunno, just seemed like a nice intermediate step.

Comment: Is there some additional unstated assumption behind "I've not been able to find a case where you can take more than $\binom n2$ steps"? It seems to me that given an energy function $\phi$ which is strictly increasing over the naturals (and, in particular, doesn't have $\phi(1) = \phi(0)$) it's trivial to construct a series of weights $c_i$ which increase exponentially by ratio $r > \phi(n)$ for which you can take $n(k-1) - 1$ steps from $(0, 0, \ldots, 0, n)$ to $(n, 0, \ldots, 0)$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for catching that--I was implicitly assuming exactly what you say, that $\phi(1) = \phi(0)$, in analogy with the quadratic case.  I've edited in a clarification.  And the most extreme case I can find is the modification of your suggestion: If each bin has essentially infinite energy compared those that follow, the worst case is starting with $(n,0,\dots,0)$ and ending in $(1,1,\dots,1)$, which takes $\binom{n}{2}$ steps.

Comment: Just to say out loud something which many people have already noticed: In the case with energy $c_i \binom{n}{2}$, or more generally whenever $\phi_i(1) = \phi_i(0)$, once a box gets a ball in it, it can never become empty. Therefore, no more than $n$ boxes can ever have balls in them, so we can assume there are at most $n$ boxes.

Comment: More generally, if there are $k$ boxes and $n \geq k$ balls, then the optimal bound appears to be $(k-1)n - \binom{k}{2}$ steps if we impose $\phi_i(1) = \phi_i(0)$, and $(k-1) n$ steps if we allow $\phi_i(1) > \phi_i(0)$. Still no idea how to prove it though!